# Overwrite attribute with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML:

```
<doc>
    <p id="123" sec="abc"></p>
</doc>
```

Using XSLT, I need to:

1) add new attribute `name` with value `'myname'`

2) copy same `sec` value

3) overwrite `id` attribute to new value

I've written the following XSLT to do that,

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p name="myname" id="999">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

It gives me following result:

```
<doc>
   <p name="myname" id="123" sec="abc"></p>
</doc>
```

The desired result is:

```
<doc>
   <p name="myname" id="999" sec="abc"></p>
</doc>
```

It seems it does not overwrite `id` attribute value. How can I overwrite this value from XSLT?

Comment: edited my answer ...

Comment: "*I've written the following XSLT to do that*" Clearly you have more than that, otherwise the result would have been different. All the answers assumed that you also have the identity transform template. You should have made that clear, instead of letting us guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the template

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <p name="myname" id="999">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <p name="myname" id="999">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @id, node()"/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>
```

or write a template for the `id` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <p name="myname">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/@id">
  <xsl:attribute name="id" select="999"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the last solution does not work for me. I've seen this solution all around the internet but it just won't change the value. If I debug it with oxygen it just executes the `xsl:attribute` line and nothing happens. The attribute value stays the same.

FYI: I work on a result-tree (tree I created inside a variable). Maybe this causes some problems?

Comment: @RobertS., consider to post a new question with minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, result you want, result you get together with information about the XSLT processor and I am sure we can tell what is wrong.

Comment: I solved my problem. I generated the same value as there was before by accident. Cause I used the parent element attribute value and concatenated the position of the child element to it. As I update the parent attribute the new value is not part of my input tree but of another result tree. Therefore the attribute values were not as expected. So your last solution works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

i can't try it myself at the moment ... please try to NOT copy 'id' attribute since this will overrule your 'id' attribute in the xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
        <p name="myname" id="999">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*[local-name() != 'id']"/>
        </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p name="myname" id="999" sec="{@sec}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

--

In case the `p` element can contain other nodes (unlike the example shown), use:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p name="myname" id="999" sec="{@sec}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>    
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key thing is that if you add several attributes with the same name to an element, the last one wins. Your explicit id="999" is considered to precede the attribute that you copy using the xsl:apply-templates call, so it has no effect.

There are several solutions. You can avoid applying templates to the @id attribute (using a select in the apply-templates); you can have a template rule for the @id attribute that does not cause it to be copied; or you could add the id="999" attribute AFTER doing the apply-templates, by means of an xsl:attribute instruction that appears after the xsl:apply-templates instruction.

Comment: "*you could add the id="999" attribute AFTER doing the apply-templates*" That would work only if the element has no children (which seems rather unlikely when the element is named `p`). And if it has no children, why would you do apply-templates at all?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, if you break it up into `<p name="myname"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:attribute name="id" select="999"/><xsl:apply-templates/></p>` then it should work.